# Accessing data from 4 seconds back

Tags: ros, msg, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I am trying to create my own acceleration node. The idea is to have the difference between 2 velocities, every 4 seconds for example. I know how to get the value of the velocity at the current time. but how do I get the velocity 4 seconds back? the value should be accessible as the program runs, or as bag files are being played.

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('kee_use_cases')
import rospy
import math
#from std_msgs.msg import String
from std_msgs.msg import *
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from geometry_msgs.msg import *


    def callback(msg):
        rospy.loginfo("Received actual forward velocity <</odom>> message! The value is %f" %msg.twist.twist.linear.x)
        if rospy.Time.now() == 0:
            vel_init = msg.twist.twist.linear.x
            buffer_function(vel_init) #?
        else:
            #how do i get the the vel_init?
            vel_last = msg.twist.twist.linear.x
            acceleration = (vel_last - vel_init)/4
            talker(acceleration)
        
    def buffer_function(vel_init):
        return vel_init
        
    
    def talker(acc):
        rospy.loginfo("x_acceleration: %f"%acc)
        pub = rospy.Publisher('x_acceleration', Float64 )
        pub.publish(acc)
        
    def listener():
        rospy.Subscriber("odom", Odometry, callback)
        
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        rospy.init_node('x_acceleration', anonymous=True)
        
        duration = 4
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            try:
                listener()
                rospy.sleep(duration)
            except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
                pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58255/accessing-data-from-4-seconds-back/) by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to save old messages in your callback in a persistent buffer.

If you need exactly four seconds, you'll probably need to interpolate between two successive messages.

If you just want to estimate acceleration, the simplest approach is storing only the previous message, and computing **dt** by subtracting the previous header.stamp from the current one.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1